# How do I roll a ball with a Rigidbody?

Tags: unity, physics

I have a ball in a game that rolls around just fine with `Rigidbody.AddForce()`.  I have other non-physics balls, however, that I control directly with `Rigidbody.MovePosition()`.

It seems that no matter what I do, no matter how interpolation and collision detection are set, the ball does not "roll" when moved with `Rigidbody.MovePosition()`. It teleports, but `IsKinematic` is *not* set , as instructed by [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html).

How do I get the ball to roll properly with `Rigidbody.MovePosition()`? Alternatively, if that's not possible, how do I calculate the rotations manually?

Comment: I'd be tempted to attack this from the opposite direction: calculate the velocities needed to move your balls to the positions you've chosen in one timestep, and let them roll there. This will have a little slop when changing directions, but in my experience the control remains tight. Whether this is an acceptable solution in your case may depend on exactly what gameplay you're trying to achieve — can you give us more details about the movement logic these balls use?

Comment: You say you do not have `IsKinematic` set, as you found from the docs. The docs *do not* mention `IsKinematic` in this way, but they *do* explicitly mention `Interpolate`. You *do* still mention trying that, am I right to assume this was just a publishing error on your behalf?

Answer (score 1):

To make the ball move naturally, you should use [`AddForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) (to make to move in a straight line) and [`AddTorque`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html) (to make it roll).